# How to make VLC play an iso file directly?

Tags: vlc

Running `vlc /path/to/dvd-video.iso`, I'm getting:

```
[0x8787ccc] main decoder error: no suitable decoder module for fourcc `undf'. VLC probably does not support this sound or video format.
```

**notes**:

- The version of `vlc` is 1.1.3.
- The DVD plays well when not in iso format (when it's normal files on the filesystem).

Comment: Does the path contain non standard characters? And what do you mean by 'extract'? Do you mean that you mount the iso file and read the contents directly?

Comment: @asoundmove The path contains normal characters; I updated the answer.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-512698.html shows a similar discussion to the one you've started here. Maybe that will help?

Comment: **update**: this works on a fresh Debian install (right-click, select VLC, and voila!) ; I don't know what the fix is

Comment: This question is not applicable to the more recent VLC versions that can play ISO-s directly.

Answer (score 6):

Mount it as a loopback first.

```
mount -o loop,ro -t iso9660 /path/to/file.iso /path/to/mountpoint/
```

Or try this...

```
vlc dvd://path/to/iso
```

Comment: That is not *directly*, unless you are suggesting a workaround?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'll bet the second option is about as directly as you will find.

Comment: Nah, 2nd option doesn't work. It expects a normal file system: `libdvdnav:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed`.

Comment: Why is it that you are opposed to mounting it?

Comment: It's extra work.

Comment: Then make a wrapper script. Name it `pi` for "play image". The script mounts, plays, unmounts automatically. Now you're typing one less character every time.

Comment: I just wanna right-click and hit play. No CLI.

Comment: @Tshepang: so probably the answer to your question is "You can't"

Comment: @kiz Actually I can. Check the update on the question (a comment).

Answer (score 2):

As this is an old question, it may be useful to say that more recent VLC (2.1 and later) versions ***should*** be able to play ISO-s directly, unless there is something wrong with the iso.

Comment: @tomas - I have changed my initial post

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use vlc? mplayer can usually work out a video dvd iso (or even a partial incomplete iso) contains mpeg streams well enough to play them without loopback mounting or complicated flags. Doing it this way means menus, subtitles, alternate soundtracks are unlikely to work tho.

```
mplayer /path/to/dvd.iso
```

Comment: Does MPlayer even support menus?

Comment: You can watch the mpeg stream behind animated menus but the hotspots aren't connected up to anything useful.